# .tfignore is not ignoring my files using wildcards

Tags: tfs, ignore

I have a project in TFS with branches and I want to ignore some folders in each branch. 
So I try this to ignore all branches folders, but it's not working:

```
\Tools\Web\APPREPORTS\Branches\*\node_modules\
\Tools\Web\APPREPORTS\Branches\*\packages\
```

So it's forcing me to do that in this way, specifing each branch:

```
\Tools\Web\ALMAREPORTS\Branches\DEV\node_modules\
\Tools\Web\ALMAREPORTS\Branches\DEV\packages\
\Tools\Web\ALMAREPORTS\Branches\STAGE\packages\
\Tools\Web\ALMAREPORTS\Branches\STAGE\node_modules\
\Tools\Web\ALMAREPORTS\Branches\PRODUCTION\packages\
\Tools\Web\ALMAREPORTS\Branches\PRODUCTION\node_modules\
```

There is another way to simplify that? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is not supported.
**The * and ? wildcards are supported in the leaf name only.**
More detailed info from this answer: [tfignore wildcard directory segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559576/tfignore-wildcard-directory-segment)

It depends which folder you put your .tfignore file in. 
You can just use `\node_modules` to ignore all files in this folder.

The following rules apply to a .tfignore file:

> # begins a comment line
>
> The * and ? wildcards are supported.
>
> A filespec is **recursive unless prefixed by the \ character.**
>
> ! negates a filespec (files that match the pattern are not ignored)
>
> Source: [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Use two asterisks:

```
\Tools\Web\APPREPORTS\Branches\**\node_modules\
\Tools\Web\APPREPORTS\Branches\**\packages\
```

Comment: Seems not working. Still detecting the "node_modules" and it's sub-folders and files.

Comment: This is .gitIgnore spec ;)